# keeping focus on iframe at all times with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I've got an HTML page with an header, a footer, a simple menu and a large iframe (yeah, i know it's sad..)

I need to keep the focus on the iframe at all times (there are keypress events on it), even when clicking on the external parts of the page...

The catch is that i can't access any of the content of the iframe (external site)

How can i accomplish this ? i've been thinking about something like this:

```
function setFoc(){
  $('#IFRAMEID').focus();
}

setInterval('setFoc()',200)
```

but i don't like it, it's a really ugly thing to do...

thankssss !

SOLVED:   see example here http://jsfiddle.net/GrqkT/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting click event handler to the body should do the trick.

```
$("body").click(function(){
  $('#IFRAMEID').focus();
});
```

It really depeneds on what element are there outside the `iframe`. 
Maybe it would be better to rewrite event handlers and send them to `iframe`?

**EDIT:**

It won't override other handlers.
See example [in fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/avall/GrqkT/).

Comment: can't rewrite anything inside the iframe, it's an external site with lots of key events.....
wouldn't your code overwrite every click event i could have on the external html ?